# Where in the filesystem does IE8 store values stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, cookies

My organization is starting to use this feature and for testing it would be ideal if we could find and delete these values as well as see what's written to disk, but I can't figure out where IE8 is storing them. I found the .sqlite files in

AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari for Safari 
and
AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ryb7f27l.default\webappsstore.sqlite for FF3.5

Any help on IE8 would be appreciated!

Comment: fyi for anyone else - http://superuser.com/questions/680867/ie10-on-windows-7-where-is-localstorage-stored-in-the-file-system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location of local storage on the file system is most likely an implementation detail that is not guaranteed to always be the same from version to version (it could even change with a service pack or update to IE).

To clear local storage using the approved methods, see [Clearing the Storage Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062.aspx#_clear) on the [Introduction to DOM Storage MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062.aspx):

> **Clearing the Storage Areas**
>
> Session state is released as soon as
>   the last window to reference that data
>   is closed. However, users can clear
>   storage areas at any time by selecting
>   **Delete Browsing History** from the **Tools**
>   menu in Internet Explorer, selecting
>   the **Cookies** check box, and clicking
>   **OK**. This clears session and local
>   storage areas for all domains that are
>   not in the Favorites folder and resets
>   the storage quotas in the registry.
>   Clear the **Preserve Favorite Site Data**
>   check box to delete all storage areas,
>   regardless of source.
>
> To delete key/value pairs from a
>   storage list, iterate over the
>   collection with [removeItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197047.aspx) or use
>   [clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288131.aspx) to remove all items at once.
>   Keep in mind that changes to a local
>   storage area are saved to disk
>   asynchronously.

An alternative to using the approved methods is to use a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch disk and Registry accesses while you write something to `window.localStorage`. Unfortunately, if you see it writing to a file like `%userprofile%\Cookies\index.dat` it would probably be unwise to delete that file (since it contains information about all the other cookies IE knows about).

EDIT: Using my own suggestion I found that local storage seems to be at `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore` (in Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7 will be slightly different). They are just XML files but I'm not sure how safe they are to delete because of the `index.dat` (which may retain information about the existence of the XML files or their contents).

Comment: Thanks, I found this and understand that it can be cleared easily via javascript's localStorage.clear() method, but for our testing, we'll want to see the actual files and maybe setup from cmd files to delete them to make testing easier.

Comment: That helped, I watched it read/write files and saw it access this path:

C:\Users\jody\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore\JPJ0UV5O\10.0.20[1].xml

The entire DOMStore\ path is hidden+system, but that's it. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @unknown: See my edits. You might be able to simply remove everything under the `DOMStore` directory in your `%userprofile%` and restart IE. *I haven't tested it, if doing that paralyzes your hamster or causes you any emotional distress, we never spoke and I don't know you. You found it on the intertubes for free, so what do you expect. Good luck.* (Thanks to Scott Hanselman for the excellent disclaimer: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StepByStepHowToUpgradeFromWindowsXPToWindows7.aspx)

Comment: LOL. Great disclaimer!

Answer (score 2):

There are also some registry settings that might relate to this under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\DOMStorage
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the localhost[1].xml from the appropriate directory under %userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore solved the problem.