# Browsers Storage - physical Location?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, cross-browser, local-storage

According to  :

```
localStorage.setItem( key , value ); // global - not per session
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John"); //per session
```

question :

**where** does it actually save the storage file/item ?

*(multi browser answer will be much appreciated).*

Comment: I would imagine it just goes in to the browser application's "Application Data" folder, or somesuch, no?

Comment: @dbaseman the only `imagine` i know - is john lennon's one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick couple of searches on Google:

For Chrome:

http://www.techskater.com/web-stuff/accessing-google-chrome-extension-local-storage-database/

For Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data

IE:

[Where in the filesystem does IE8 store values stored in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412083/where-in-the-filesystem-does-ie8-store-values-stored-in-localstorage)

Comment: To bad the information is not posted here, since the chrome link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Some other stackoverflow answers have additional details:

- Chrome: [How is HTML5 WebStorage data physically stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669184/how-is-html5-webstorage-data-physically-stored/14887525#14887525)
- Firefox: [Where does firefox store javascript/HTML localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage/14901354#14901354)
- Opera: [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored/15711210#15711210)

Answer (score 0):

The links for the storage-area for chrome no longer works and the information on the Mozilla site is not of much use.

Windows 7: The physical location for chrome is within AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage and for Mozilla its AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\uvsb3rxs.default\storage\persistent\moz-safe-about+home

I have not found Internet Explorer's localstorage folder. If any person knows its whereabouts, please let me know.

Regards