# will javascript local storage propogate to other users on same windows 7 PC?

Tags: javascript, windows

I have app users that share Windows 7 PC's but will logon to their respective accounts. I would like to set some default values for each user like Employee ID. If I set a localstorage key/value pair for User A will the same localstorage key/value pair be available to User B?

Comment: Question is not about Windows but about the browser you're using. Anyway...no, local storage isn't shared across users (unless you're using some weird browser or some esotheric setup in Chrome/IE/something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage (in Chrome) is in the [`%LocalAppData%`](https://superuser.com/a/508207) directory, which is under the [user's account](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/mmpc/shared/variables.aspx).  Internet Explorer stores them under [`%userprofile%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412136/1216976)
 Precise location varies among browsers but is always within a user folder.

So no, LocalStorage will not propagate across users.

Comment: For [IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412083/where-in-the-filesystem-does-ie8-store-values-stored-in-localstorage)

Comment: LOL LOL yes, "IE" word is a link!

Comment: @Adriano Ha!  I completely missed that.  Nice work, thanks for the help.