# Changing Local Storage directory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask: is there any method to change "localStorage" (JavaScript) directory? I don't want to store informations about user in browers' file because it is (by me) very unsafe.

So? How can I change Local Storage directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where in the filesystem does IE8 store values stored in localStorage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412083/where-in-the-filesystem-does-ie8-store-values-stored-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** You have no access to the filesystem. You don't ever save a user's information, you save a auth token that allows them to use that account. All the private information is saved on the server unless the user wants their browser to remember their passwords. What would be more dangerous than storing the user's information locally and unencrypted is if we gave browsers access to our filesystem without asking for permission.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` isn't aimed to store sensitive informations. You cannot modify the settings of the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Chrome you can specify the location of the local storage and other config ... somehow ... A while ago I used the Portable Chrome, which stores all profile data alongside with the binaries.

And I'm quite sure, also for Firefox there's an config option where the profile is stored. At least, there is also a portable version of Firefox.

Is this what you are looking for?